# Не отображается текст из файла в ListBox-e

Tags: c#, listbox

После перезагрузки компьютера перестали выводиться данные из файла в ListBox, но при этом ошибок при компиляции не выявляются, просто при нажатии кнопки ничего не появляется в ListBox. Имеется 2 варианта реализации чтения из файла

Первый

```
 string value0 = textBox2.Text;
        switch (value0)
        {
            case "НЕТ":
                listBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("pokazateli/harakter1/0(1).txt");

                break;
            case "1":
                listBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("pokazateli/harakter1/1.txt");

                break;
            case "11":
                listBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("pokazateli/harakter1/11.txt");

                break;
            case "111":
                listBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("pokazateli/harakter1/111.txt");

                break;
            case "1111":
                listBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("pokazateli/harakter1/111.txt");

                break;
            case "11111":
                listBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("pokazateli/harakter1/11111.txt");

                break;
            case "111111":
                listBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("pokazateli/harakter1/111111.txt");

                break;
        }
```

Второй

```
string value1 = textBox2.Text;        
        switch (value1)
        {
            case "НЕТ":
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"0(1).txt");
                listBox1.DataSource = lines;

                break;
            case "1":
                lines = File.ReadAllLines("pokazateli/harakter1/1.txt");
                listBox1.DataSource = lines;

                break;
            case "11":
                lines = File.ReadAllLines("pokazateli/harakter1/11.txt");
                listBox1.DataSource = lines;

                break;
            case "111":
                lines = File.ReadAllLines("pokazateli/harakter1/111.txt");
                listBox1.DataSource = lines;

                break;
            case "1111":
                lines = File.ReadAllLines("pokazateli/harakter1/1111.txt");
                listBox1.DataSource = lines;

                break;
            case "11111":
                lines = File.ReadAllLines("pokazateli/harakter1/11111.txt");
                listBox1.DataSource = lines;

                break;
            case "111111":
                lines = File.ReadAllLines("pokazateli/harakter1/111111.txt");
                listBox1.DataSource = lines;

                break;
        }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чтение из текстового файла в ListBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844772/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

listBox - контрол, состоящий из множества строк. И при добавлении в него текста нужно явно указывать строку, в которую добавляется текст

```
private void AddText(string txt)
    {
        list.Items.Add(txt);
    }
```

Либо вначале создать источник строк для listBox, реализующий интерфейс IList, например

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
```

Затем добавить туда необходимые строки, и наконец:

```
listBox1.DataSource = lst;
```